# Not able to install mongodb in OSX 10.11.4

Tags: macos, mongodb

I am trying to install mongoDb manually in my Mac.

OS Version : 10.11.4

I am getting below error when i run ./mongodb from bin folder.

2016-04-26T15:51:25.630-0700 W NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain address information for hostname MNGKTR971L: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Please let me know on what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your dns server if you have one.  My guess is this is a standalone box so you need to update your /etc/hosts file to include your hostsname which I believe is mngktr971 from you description. The entry would look like this:
127.0.0.1    mngktr971

Comment: Updated the /etc/hosts file to add 127.0.01  MNGKTR971L..it worked!!